# How do I take input from the python console to be able to send messages as a Discord BOT?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I just want to be able to send messages as a bot taking input from the python console. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  channel = client.get_channel(845291402803937311)
  await channel.send("Im on!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  author = message.author
  content = message.content
  server = message.guild
  channel = message.channel
  print('{} | #{} | {}: {}'.format(server, channel, author, content))
  outfile = open('messages.txt','a')
  outfile.write('{} | #{} | {}: {}\n'.format(server, channel, author, content))

client.run("Token")
```

Comment: Maybe [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) would be sufficient here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the discord bot utilizes asyncio you would also need an asyncio compatible input.
I would suggest to use the package [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) which provides the function: `ainput` to capture input asynchronously.

You can then for example rewrite your `on_ready` function like such:

```
import aioconsole

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  channel = client.get_channel(845291402803937311)
  msg = await aioconsole.ainput("Input your message: ")
  await channel.send(msg)
```

Then the discord bot would ask you for input and would then send the message to your channel!